# Use Completion Suggester to match against all ngrams in a query

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, named-entity-recognition, text-chunking

I'd like to know if it's possible to use [Elasticsearch's Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) to match against all ngrams in a query.

What I basically want to do is 'misuse' Completion Suggester to do "Dictionary based chunking".

For example given the sentence: "Until what time is the crazy horse club in Paris open today?"

I'd like to input the entire sentence above as query to the 'Completion Suggester' and get back the indexed 'the crazy horse club' but not 'horse club' even if both could be indexed. I.e.: only the largest ngram should be returned if there's an overlap in terms.

Is this possible out of the box?
If not, any directions (with or without Elasticsearch) on where to look?

Comment: It's still a pilot code but there's https://github.com/alvations/Terminator